# How to have a different .gitignore for each branch (or an alternative solution)?

Tags: git

I have the following setup:

origin/master                               origin/my-branch 
-----------------              ----------------------

test.txt                   
       |                                           | 
       |                                           |

       |                                           |

local/master                   local/my-branch 
-----------------              ----------------------

test.txt                       test.txt

The idea is that I need to have different test.txt files on each branch, consider them like config files. test.txt needs to be however, on origin/master, in case someone else wants to clone the project, to have a default working config. 
 I want to have my test.txt file (modified with my own configurations) and I also don't want to push it to remote on my-branch because I would later on merge it into master, and my configurations would override the default test.txt.
How can I achieve this? I was thinking of using 2 different .gitignore for each branch, but modifying .gitignore on one branch, modifies it on the other. Also, because test.txt on local/my-branch is not committed to remote, every time I checkout to master and checkout back, the file is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you need one config file which is checked in, and a second config file which is ignored. The first contains the default configuration. The second contains your local modifications which override the defaults. How you accomplish this depends on your project.

Here's a simple example in Ruby using YAML config files.

```
config = YAML.load_file('config.yml')
local_config = YAML.load_file('local_config.yml')
config.merge!( local_config )
```

This is beneficial not just for development but for your users as well. They can keep the default config file pristine allowing it to be cleanly updated when new versions become available. Their local changes go into the local config file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible on my project. It's an enterprise-level application and its not within my grasp, I cannot customize my local config to overwrite the main config of the application.  Thanks, anyways.